# nicematrix matrix vs array - alignment specification

Tags: nicematrix

I recently found the `nicematrix` package, and I am using it to for scripting.

Since my goal is to have a macro/environment which makes an augmented matrix (vertical line before the last column in my case), I was searching for a way to pass something like `RRR|R` as format string to `pNiceMatrix`.

Soon I figured out that this is not possible (right?) and found that the `NiceArray` environment would support this.

Since setting the parentheses is not a problem (I can specify this in my macro/environment declaration, thus later this is irrelevant),

I was wondering if I'd have any drawbacks by moving from `pNiceMatrix` to `NiceArray`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a matrix with (let's say) 3 columns, there is no difference between `{pNiceMatrix}` and `{pNiceArray}{CCC}`.

If you want a vertical rule, indeed, you need `{pNiceArray}` in order to have a explicit preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\qquad
\begin{pNiceArray}{CCC}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 
\end{pNiceArray}
\qquad
\begin{pNiceArray}{CC|C}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Ok thanks. This is the last step of my `gaussMatrix` environment for now. I've got just one little problem with pgfkeys and nicematrix (new post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548110/pgfkeys-and-nicematrix-calculate-with-pgfkeys-and-use-in-niceatrix-preamble)

Comment: You should accept the answer. I will see the other question.

Comment: Thanks for the remainder ;)   Now I think I'm finish with the environment (for now), if you're interested, look at https://gitlab.com/AtticusSullivan/gaussenv ;) (and thanks for all your help again)

Comment: In this answer, since version 5.0 of `nicematrix` one must write `c` instead of `C` in the preambles of  the `{pNiceArray}` (but there is an option for backward compatibility).